# Bootstrap 4 via Webpack install

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

If I install Bootstrap 4 via Webpack like the below in my app.js:

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

Do I have to also install jquery and popper.js like:

```
import 'jquery';

import popper from 'popper.js';
```

Or are the already pulled as peer dependencies from my package.json?

The reason I ask is because I had initially did an import for all 3 files. However, I did a test with just the import 'bootstrap' and everything still seemed to work fine.

Comment: The documentation suggests you would need to load them separately: "Bootstrap is dependent on jQuery and Popper, these are defined as peerDependencies, this means that you will have to make sure to add both of them to your package.json using npm install --save jquery popper.js." https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery and popper.js are defined as **peerDependencies** in the [Bootstrap `package.json`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8a628b943cf31ca0a002c08af661a95772480225/package.json#L83):

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
  "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
},
```

So when you run `npm install`, you'll get a warning if either of those 2 dependencies are not already installed. To install them, you'd run:

```
npm install --save jquery popper.js
```

Otherwise, you already have them installed. You can look inside of your `node_modules` folder for installed dependencies.

See the relevant Bootstrap documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/).

Comment: Thanks. I guess this may be more of a webpack question. I have them in package.json. In my app.js I then write ' import boostrap; ' Do I then have to do the same for popper.js as in ' import popper from popper.js ' ?

Comment: Nope, Bootstrap will work correctly without those imports so long as you have those peer dependencies installed. The only reason you'd need to import them is if you needed to directly use jQuery or popper.js in one of your modules.

Comment: Ah. Thanks! That clears things up. Your reference to jQuery rings a bell as I think I need to make some sort of export to use it and not load it twice for other applications. I'll have to read up on it.